# Take Strings from Text file and assign each line to value (2 at a time and insert into LinkedHashMap)

Tags: java, file-io, dictionary, bufferedreader

What I'm trying to do is, load a Text file, then take the values from each line and assign them to a variable in my program. Every two lines, I will insert them into a `LinkedHashMap` (As a pair)

The problem with a buffered reader is, all I can seem to do is, read one line at a time.

Here is my current code:

```
public static void receiver(String firstArg) {// Receives
                                                // Input
                                                // File
    String cipherText;
    String key;
    String inFile = new File(firstArg).getAbsolutePath();
    Path file = new File(inFile).toPath();

    // File in = new File(inFile);
    try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in))) {
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // System.out.println(line);
            String[] arrayLine = line.split("\n"); // here you are
                                                    // splitting
                                                    // with whitespace

            cipherText = arrayLine[0];
            // key = arrayLine[1];
            System.out.println(arrayLine[0] + " " + arrayLine[1]);

            cipherKeyPairs.put(arrayLine[0], arrayLine[1]);
        }
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.println(x);
    }
```

The problem is, it can't find the `arrayLine[1]` (for obvious reasons). I need it to read two lines at a time without the array going out of bounds.

Any idea how to do this, so that I can store them into my `LinkedHashMap`, two lines at a time as separate values.

Comment: Why don't you add a flag to tell you every two lines you read then insert them as a pair

Comment: @AhmedHamdy I don't know how to do that :P never even heard of that concept

Comment: Okay let me make an answer :)

Comment: If its not a large file, you can read everything into an array and create the pairs from the array

Comment: @unekwu How would I do that though?

Comment: Just a minor edit to your code. Put the array outside the loop. read everything into it. Then loop through the array and create the pair

Comment: @unekwu How do I "read everything into it"? Sorry for the needy sounding questions :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overcome this issue by inserting in the  List every 2 lines reading.
A description for this code is that: "Bold is the true case"

1. Read the first line (count is 0)

   - **If (secondLine is false) ==> Save the line to CipherText variable, make secondLine = true**
   - Else If (secondLine is true) ==> Add to list (CipherText, line), make secondLine = false
2. Read the second line (count is 1)

   - If (secondLine is false) ==> Save the line to CipherText variable, make secondLine = true
   - **Else If (secondLine is true) ==> Add to list (CipherText, line), make secondLine = false**

---

```
String cipherText;
boolean secondLine = false;
String inFile = new File(firstArg).getAbsolutePath();
Path file = new File(inFile).toPath();

try {
    InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {

    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {


        if (!secondLine) //first line reading
        {
            cipherText = line; 
            secondLine = true;
        }
        else if (secondLine) //second line reading
        {   
            cipherKeyPairs.put(cipherText, line);
            secondLine = false;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Comment: The problem is, I NEED to have it so that he actual String key is stored AS the key in the Map, therefor I don't think this code would work :/

Comment: I think this is more efficient and the OP should apply this. If you format your code, I'll vote on it.

Comment: the problem still remains I think. What I need to happen is, I need to insert the cipherText and key into the map at the SAME time. The as in,  cipherKeyPairs.put(cipherText, key);    Thanks for the continued support, means a TON

Comment: @Sully Whats the key? I thought you were trying to insert pairs of lines?

Comment: @SullyBrooks That is what the code do... Did you read my explanation, what I wrote in bold is case which will be activated, so you will read the first line and not inserting anything in the map, then read the second line and **here** only you will insert the first line and second line together.
So I can say you will insert in the map every 2 lines read :)

Comment: Okay, so the first line, is the cipherText (first arg for the cipherKeyPairs.put() ) the key is the second line in the text file

Comment: @AhmedHamdy testing it now :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, read the cipher, then the value, then insert them together, like I did in this line:
`cipherKeyPairs.put(cipherText, line);`

Comment: Ahmed, you sir, are my HERO. Thanks so much for this, its working right now perfectly, and I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @AhmedHamdy one problem is, it isn't adding EVERY single pair. It seems to have missed the last one!

Comment: Send me the case and I will figure it out

Comment: @ahmedhamdy Here is my input file:  KFFOP
CAT
JXK
FIDO
JPWIWTHBRPPDPNFHBRPP
ABCDEFGHI
USPVCMF
A
USPVCMF
AAAAAAA
B
BCDEFGHIJ             I can't format it :/   but every two lines is obviously what I need, but it does all of them except for the last pair!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44545/discussion-between-sully-brooks-and-ahmed-hamdy)

Comment: BTW I tested it and it works great with this test cases:
(KHYFG, CAT),  
(KHYVN, DOG), 
(OPTWRG KDDH, DONKEY A)

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you. I just edited your code. it might not be the best answer.

```
public static void receiver(String firstArg) {// Receives
                                            // Input
                                            // File
    String cipherText;
    String key;
    String inFile = new File(firstArg).getAbsolutePath();
    Path file = new File(inFile).toPath();

// File in = new File(inFile);
    try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in))) {
        String line = null;
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

           lines.add(line);//trim line first though and check for empty string
        }

        for(int i=1;i<lines.size();i++){
             cipherText = arrayLine[i];
            // key = arrayLine[1];
            System.out.println(arrayLine[i] + " " + arrayLine[i-1]);

            cipherKeyPairs.put(arrayLine[i-1], arrayLine[i]);
        }
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, I NEED to have it so that he actual String key is stored AS the key in the Map, therefor I don't think this code would work :/

Comment: I just updated my answer. I think Ahmed's answer is more efficient though if you can make that work